# How to load the values of three column from one table1 to another table 2 which is having single column in hive?

Tags: hadoop, hive, subquery, bigdata, derived-column

Could you please help me below query.

[image]

**Table 1** (Input)had three columns (Credit_date, Debit_date, Payment_date) and
**Table 2** (Output) has one column date

The three column values from **Table 1** should be available in **Table 2**.

I tried below query but not working.

```
insert into table2
select date 
from (
 (select credit_date, debit_date, Payment_date from table 1) as date)t;
```

Could you please guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing a union all:

```
insert into table2 
select * from (
select credit_date as date from table1
union all
select debit_date as date from table1
union all
select payment_date as date from table1
) t
```